# Why does Expectation function compute, while explicit integration does not?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, distributions

The code:

```
Expectation[1 + 1/y, {y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]}]
```

outputs

```
1 - EulerGamma
```

While,

```
Integrate[(1 + 1/y) Exp[-y], {y, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

does not compute. Presumably `Expectation` is using something that I am not giving to `Integrate`. Something like domain specifications, like in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35642/why-does-fouriertransform-converge-while-same-integral-manually-written-does-n) example. Maybe whether or not it includes `y=0`? Any suggestions for how to make this consistent? I presume `Expectation` is correct, but I was very surprised to see a result since `Integrate[1/y Exp[-y], {y, 0, \[Infinity]}]` of course does not converge for intervals starting at 0, so why would *adding 1* help?!

Comment: `Integrate[(1 + 1/y)  (E^(-y)), {y, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Using `NIntegrate`, it is fairly clear that the integral does not converge.  I guess that `Expectation` is using some formula that is outside its domain of validity.

Comment: @mikado - I'd expect and expectation of infinity... and in fact `Mean@TransformedDistribution[
  1 + 1/y, {y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]}]` gives just that.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I still don't know what the are conditions whose removal gives the `1 - EulerGamma` answer, but common sense concensus is that it must be wrong.

Comment: @puelmato Consider reporting the situation to Wolfram support as a possible bug.

Comment: @MarcoB Did this and they confirmed the incorrect behavior.