# FourierTransform and Integrate don't agree

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fourier-analysis

With the input

```
f[t_] := Cos[2 Pi t]
FourierTransform[f[t], t, w, FourierParameters -> {0, -2*Pi}]
```

I get `1/2 DiracDelta[-1 + w] + 1/2 DiracDelta[1 + w]` as expected.  But unless I'm having a brain fart, this implies that

```
Integrate[f[t]*Exp[-2 Pi I t 3], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

is zero.  Mathematica, however, claims that this integral doesn't converge.  I could understand if `FourierTransform` used other methods internally and thus `Integrate` doesn't find a solution.  But I'm a bit surprised that I get the apodictic claim that the integral doesn't converge.  What am I missing?  Are there any options to `Integrate` or any assumptions I could use to make Mathematica change its mind?

BTW, I am aware of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35642/why-does-fouriertransform-converge-while-same-integral-manually-written-does-n), but although it's related it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: What's strange here? The integral diverge? period. Fourier transform command deals with distributions and action of the FT on those are not integrating generally. It's a more widely defined mapping.

Comment: Stated differently, not every FT can be recast as a convergent integral.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `Integrate` will not produce generalized functions like `DiracDelta` as results. I don't believe there is a strategy that will produce consistent results in general for such (formally divergent) 
integrals. `FourierTransform` is restricted to Fourier integrals, a relatively safe domain.